# Is there a way to implant tkinter input box into my turtle screen (to create paint)

Tags: python, tkinter, python-turtle

I have this code taken from trinket.io

```
import turtle

tina = turtle.Turtle()

tina.shape("turtle")

# promt user for color and make turtle that color
turtle_color = input("What color should tina the turtle be?")

tina.color(turtle_color)

# promt user for background color and makes it that color

myscreen = turtle.Screen()
background_color = input("What color should background be?")
myscreen.bgcolor(background_color)
```

What I would like to do is that I would like to merge my tkinter inputbox into one side of the program and create a sort of paint like program

this is the code for tkinter button:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
e = Entry(master)
e.pack()

e.focus_set()

def callback():
    print e.get() # This is the text you may want to use later

b = Button(master, text = "OK", width = 10, command = callback)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

we could also merge it with the turtle demo program in python which could sort of create paint..

So I just wanted to know how to merge them

by merging I mean the tkinter button and input box in one side of the turtle
answer is still accepted.. thank you

Comment: Turtle is based on Tkinter, so there is a way to embed other Tkinter widgets to Turtle programs. You just need to specify `myscreen._root` as a master, or use `myscreen._canvas` in another Tkinter window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turtle is based on Tkinter, so there is a way to embed other Tkinter widgets to Turtle programs. You can do it in several ways:

1. go with @cdlane's answer. It is the cleanest one and it uses Turtle's documented interface, specially designed for embedding it in Tkinter apps.
2. take a look at the second part of @volothud's answer (the first one is described below).
3. You just need either to specify `myscreen._root` as a master of a widget or to use `myscreen._canvas` in another Tkinter window.

Here is an example for the third option:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring
import turtle


tina = turtle.Turtle()
tina.shape("turtle")

screen = turtle.Screen()
root = screen._root

controls = tk.Frame(root)
tk.Label(controls, text="Move forward:").pack(side=tk.LEFT)
fwd_entry = tk.Entry(controls)
fwd_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
tk.Button(controls, text="Go!", command=lambda: tina.forward(int(fwd_entry.get()))).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
controls.pack()

tina_color = askstring("Tina's color", "What color should Tina the turtle be?")
bg_color = askstring("The background color", "What color should the background be?")
tina.color(tina_color)
screen.bgcolor(bg_color)

root.mainloop()
```

**Note 1**: why are you using `input(...)` (which is for terminal/command-line) together with GUI? You can use `tkinter.simpledialog` instead (see the code snippet above).

**Note 2**: Inputs are not validated, so the user can enter anything (you can catch them with try/except and show the error dialog with tkinter.messagebox).

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219977/demianwolf-and-rupanugapmishra

Comment: Damn, you stole the answer:P Just kidding. Good one. Also modified my own (just a simple root change).

Answer (score 2):

Although the answers you've received so far work, I argue that they are assembled backward, if not incorrectly.  The hint is their use of an undocumented interface:

```
root = screen._root
assert isinstance(tina.screen._root, tk.Tk)
```

Turtle *knows* it's implemented in tkinter, and along with the standard *standalone* interface, it documents an *embedded* interface for when you mix turtle with tkinter.  Reworking @volothud's example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring
from turtle import TurtleScreen, RawTurtle

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=480)
canvas.pack()

distance = tk.IntVar()

controls = tk.Frame(root)
tk.Label(controls, text="Move forward:").pack(side=tk.LEFT)
tk.Entry(controls, textvariable=distance).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
tk.Button(controls, text="Go!", command=lambda: turtle.forward(distance.get())).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
controls.pack()

turtle_color = askstring("Turtle's color", "What color should the turtle be?")
background_color = askstring("Background color", "What color should the background be?")

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.bgcolor(background_color)

turtle = RawTurtle(screen)
turtle.shape('turtle')
turtle.color(turtle_color)

root.mainloop()
```

Otherwise, if you're not careful, you can end up with two roots.  This can cause bugs further down the road, like unexplainable errors upon loading images.

Comment: These are all just options. Another option: there is no need to create a root; since turtle creates one internally, all tkinter widgets 
after it, can be created without explicitly specifying root 
(and call tk.mainloop() directly @end). And there is nothing 
wrong with multiple Tk roots; don't know where this notion 
came from (seen it before in stack overflow). Problems arise 
when multiple Tk roots are used incorrectly (the automagic 
implicit creation of a default global root in various cases, 
probably contributes to that).

Answer (score 1):

It seems fine. Just merge your turtle & tkinter code, e.g.:

```
import tkinter as tk
import turtle

# Setup turtle

tina = turtle.Turtle()
tina.shape("turtle")
tina.color('red')
myscreen = turtle.Screen()
myscreen.bgcolor('black')

# Setup GUI

# Use independent Tk root:
#root = tk.Tk()
# Use the same Tk root with turtle:
assert isinstance(tina.screen._root, tk.Tk)  # True
root = tina.screen._root

distVar = tk.IntVar(root)
distEntry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=distVar)
distEntry.pack()
distEntry.focus_set()

def moveFwd():
  tina.forward(distVar.get())
fwdBtn = tk.Button(root, text='MoveFwd', command=moveFwd)
fwdBtn.pack()

# After setup is done (turtle, widgets & event-callbacks),
# enter event-loop (&react to user input in event-callbacks)
root.mainloop()
```

---

Just so people stop quoting the original example as "bad",
here's an even simpler one:
(Again, these are all just options (for a simple problem).)

```
import tkinter as tk
import turtle

# Setup turtle.
# This will create a Tk root, that can be implicitly reused.
t = turtle.Turtle()

# Setup tkinter GUI.

distVar = tk.IntVar()
distEntry = tk.Entry(textvariable=distVar)
distEntry.pack()
distEntry.focus_set()

def moveFwd(): t.forward(distVar.get())
fwdBtn = tk.Button(text='MoveFwd', command=moveFwd)
fwdBtn.pack()

# After setup is done (turtle, widgets & event-callbacks),
# enter event-loop (&react to user input in event-callbacks)
tk.mainloop()  # Also known as "turtle.done()".
```